# How do I successfully insert DataFrame into SqlAlChemy?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

These are my codes

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Integer, String, Boolean, Enum, Float, ForeignKey, DateTime

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///logfilesdb.db', echo=True)
df.to_sql("logfile", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={
                      "IP": Integer,
                      "date": DateTime, 
                      "time": DateTime,
                      "request_type": String(4),
                      "URL": String(50),
                      "status_code": Integer})

engine.execute("SELECT * FROM logfile").fetchall()
```

However, the datetime in SqlAlChemy is giving me problem as i could not successfully insert it into the db.

This is my error message that ive got. I am unable to call out the data from SqlAlChemy using for loop.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1178 
-> 1179             context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
   1180         except BaseException as e:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in _init_compiled(cls, dialect, connection, dbapi_connection, compiled, parameters)
    746                     if key in processors:
--> 747                         param.append(processors[key](compiled_params[key]))
    748                     else:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py in process(value)
    739                 raise TypeError(
--> 740                     "SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python "
    741                     "datetime and date objects as input."

TypeError: SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

StatementError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-177-345b3630fd58> in <module>
     11                       "request_type": String(4),
     12                       "URL": String(50),
---> 13                       "status_code": Integer})
     14 
     15 engine.execute("SELECT * FROM logfile").fetchall()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
   2710             chunksize=chunksize,
   2711             dtype=dtype,
-> 2712             method=method,
   2713         )
   2714 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
    516         chunksize=chunksize,
    517         dtype=dtype,
--> 518         method=method,
    519     )
    520 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method)
   1318         )
   1319         table.create()
-> 1320         table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
   1321         if not name.isdigit() and not name.islower():
   1322             # check for potentially case sensitivity issues (GH7815)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in insert(self, chunksize, method)
    754 
    755                 chunk_iter = zip(*[arr[start_i:end_i] for arr in data_list])
--> 756                 exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
    757 
    758     def _query_iterator(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter)
    668         """
    669         data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
--> 670         conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
    671 
    672     def _execute_insert_multi(self, conn, keys, data_iter):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in execute(self, object_, *multiparams, **params)
    986             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(object_)
    987         else:
--> 988             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    989 
    990     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    285     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
    286         if self.supports_execution:
--> 287             return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    288         else:
    289             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
   1105             distilled_params,
   1106             compiled_sql,
-> 1107             distilled_params,
   1108         )
   1109         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1180         except BaseException as e:
   1181             self._handle_dbapi_exception(
-> 1182                 e, util.text_type(statement), parameters, None, None
   1183             )
   1184 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1471                 util.raise_from_cause(newraise, exc_info)
   1472             elif should_wrap:
-> 1473                 util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
   1474             else:
   1475                 util.reraise(*exc_info)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_from_cause(exception, exc_info)
    396     exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = exc_info
    397     cause = exc_value if exc_value is not exception else None
--> 398     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
    399 
    400 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
    150             value.__cause__ = cause
    151         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 152             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    153         raise value
    154 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1177                 conn = self._revalidate_connection()
   1178 
-> 1179             context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
   1180         except BaseException as e:
   1181             self._handle_dbapi_exception(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in _init_compiled(cls, dialect, connection, dbapi_connection, compiled, parameters)
    745                 for key in positiontup:
    746                     if key in processors:
--> 747                         param.append(processors[key](compiled_params[key]))
    748                     else:
    749                         param.append(compiled_params[key])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py in process(value)
    738             else:
    739                 raise TypeError(
--> 740                     "SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python "
    741                     "datetime and date objects as input."
    742                 )

StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
[SQL: INSERT INTO logfile ("IP", date, time, "request type", "URL", "status code") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: [{'IP': '10.128.2.1', 'date': '29/11/2017', 'time': '06:58:55', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'login.php', 'status code': '200'}, {'IP': '10.128.2.1', 'date': '29/11/2017', 'time': '06:59:02', 'request type': 'POST', 'URL': 'process.php', 'status code': '302'}, {'IP': '10.128.2.1', 'date': '29/11/2017', 'time': '06:59:03', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'home.php', 'status code': '200'}, {'IP': '10.131.2.1', 'date': '29/11/2017', 'time': '06:59:04', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'js/vendor/moment.min.js', 'status code': '200'}, {'IP': '10.130.2.1', 'date': '29/11/2017', 'time': '06:59:06', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js', 'status code': '200'}, {'IP': '10.130.2.1', 'date': '29/11/2017', 'time': '06:59:19', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'profile.php?user=bala', 'status code': '200'}, {'IP': '10.128.2.1', 'date': '29/11/2017', 'time': '06:59:19', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'js/jquery.min.js', 'status code': '200'}, {'IP': '10.131.2.1', 'date': '29/11/2017', 'time': '06:59:19', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'js/chart.min.js', 'status code': '200'}  ... displaying 10 of 14927 total bound parameter sets ...  {'IP': '10.130.2.1', 'date': '03/02/2018', 'time': '15:47:35', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'allsubmission.php', 'status code': '200'}, {'IP': '10.130.2.1', 'date': '03/02/2018', 'time': '15:47:46', 'request type': 'GET', 'URL': 'home.php', 'status code': '200'}]]
```

This is an example of how my dataframe look like.

```
**IP    date    time    request type    URL status code**
0   10.128.2.1  29/11/2017  06:58:55    GET login.php   200
1   10.128.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:02    POST    process.php 302
2   10.128.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:03    GET home.php    200
3   10.131.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:04    GET js/vendor/moment.min.js 200
4   10.130.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:06    GET bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js 200
5   10.130.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:19    GET profile.php?user=bala   200
6   10.128.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:19    GET js/jquery.min.js    200
7   10.131.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:19    GET js/chart.min.js 200
8   10.131.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:30    GET edit.php?name=bala  200
9   10.131.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:37    GET logout.php  302
10  10.131.2.1  29/11/2017  06:59:37    GET login.php   200
```

The desired result should be that i can view the information in DB using query.

Comment: From [sqllite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) "SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC."

Comment: Or trying using `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` first

Comment: I did that previously in the dataframe before inserting it to sqlalchemy

Comment: Are you sure? why is the format your trying to insert like `'29/11/2017'`

Comment: I changed the format of datetime using df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'). So do i change the data type for date and time to integer instead ?

Comment: try leaving it as `datetime` type, you've cast it back to `object` (str) by doing this - ie don't do `.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: Your recommendation really helped! However, what data type should i use to store my time column? if i change it to integer it does not flag any error.

Comment: do they need to be separate columns? Might be easier to insert as one timestamp column

Comment: Okay! i will try it out. Thanks Chris.